# Interact variables from included file?

Tags: php

I have a language file, which checks browser language first and includes different language sentences. Here is how it looks like

**language.php**

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

if ($lang=="TR") {
$lang = "TR";
} else {
$lang = "EN";
}


$k1['TR'] = "Bana bu profilden ulaşabilirsiniz.";
$k1['EN'] = "You can reach me in this profile.";
```

I include that language file in index.php, and tried to echo the sentence.

**index.php**

```
include("language.php");
echo $k1[$lang];
```

However, it doesnt echo the sentence. If I use echo in language file, it works, but in index.php it doesnt.

The reason I declared $lang variable in language.php is that I have not just index.php, 10+ files, and its a big time loss when adding new languages. So I need to do in this way.

Is there a way to make correct interaction between these files ?

Comment: can you provide the notice/warning you get?

Comment: No errors, it just simply empty. Doesn'T echo.

Comment: try an `echo $lang` at index.php...what you get?